# obtains EMEI with TelephonyManager

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the number of emei identification of dispositvo and I've tried this method but I always returns null:

**CODE:**

```
private String getEmei()
    {
        String Emei="";
        try
        {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Emei=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }

        if (Emei==null)
        {
            return "";
        }

        Long suma_digitos =Long.valueOf(Emei);

        if (suma_digitos==0) 
            return "";
        else
        {
            //Log.i("Emei","emei: "+Emei+"\n");
            return Emei;
        }
    }
```

Not if you have to put some permission on the file or manifiest.xml which is the solution.

I do not care whether the IMEI or other device number that is unique.

thank you very much for trying to help with your time.

Comment: add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`permission to your manifiest.xml

Comment: @Furqan i've tried it but it not works, emei is an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

***Main.java***

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Getting the Object of TelephonyManager 
        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //Getting the SIM card ID
        String simId=tManager.getSimSerialNumber();

        //Getting Phone Number
        String tnumber=tManager.getLine1Number();

        //Getting IMEI Number of Devide
        String Imei=tManager.getDeviceId();

        TextView s=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.simid);//Getting TexView from main.xml to Display SIM Card Id
        s.setText("Sim id - "+simId);//Displaying SIM card Id in the TextView
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phoneno);//getting TextView from main.xml to display Phone Number
        t.setText("Phone No - "+tnumber);//Displaying the Phone Number.
        TextView i=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.imeino);//Getting the TextView to display IMEI number
        t.setText("IMEI number - "+Imei);//Displaying IMEI number



    }
}
```

**Layout XML code: `main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone Detail"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<!-- TextView to display SIM Card id -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/simid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<!-- TextView to Display IMEI no -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imeino"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<!-- TextView to Display Phone Number -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

***And your `AndroidManifest.xml`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imei"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <!-- Permission to Read Phone Detail such as IMEI no,SIM Card Id etc -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Main" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what you are getting ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the phone number that is unique. First thought in the IMEI but seeing your post and find in it the SIM card number is perhaps best SIM or the phone number

Comment: Thank you very much, your code if it works, well it gives me the IMEI and phone number, the number IdSIM but not so true for me what I'm doing. I relocated permission, do not ought to have put well.